# Jquery flippy keeps flipping on mouseenter in firefox

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, flippy

I use flippy plugin http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/. I have implemented it and it works fine in the opera but in FF it keeps flipping http://dev.barchick.com/barchicks-high-fives/ (hover on image).

The main code

```
<div class="high " style="background-color:#28282A">
            <img src="http://barchick/wp-content/themes/barchick-v3/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://barchick/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/park2.jpg&w=193&h=282" />
                <div id="highroll" >
                <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><span class="highbold">1. Camden Town Brewery,</span> NW5</a><br/>
                <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><span class="highbold">2. Brewdog,</span> NW1</a><br/>
                <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><span class="highbold">3. The Euston Tap,</span> NW1</a><br/>
                <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><span class="highbold">4. Duke's Brew & Cue,</span> N1</a><br/>
                <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><span class="highbold">5. Jagaur Shoes,</span> N2</a>
                </div>
            <h5 id="hightext">Best bars near parks</h5>
        </div>

                <!--    Added by Alex   -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".high").bind('mouseenter', function(){
            $(".high").flippy({
                content:$(".high"),
                direction:"TOP",
                duration:"750",
                onFinish:function(){
                    $('#highroll').show();
                    $('#hightext').hide();
                    $(".high").css('backgroundColor', '#28282A');
                }
            });
        })
        $(".high").bind('mouseleave', function(){
            $(".high").flippy({
                content:$(".high"),
                direction:"TOP",
                duration:"750",
                onFinish:function(){
                    $('#highroll').hide();
                    $('#hightext').show();
                    $(".high").css('backgroundColor', '#28282A');
                }
            });
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong and how to fix that?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?  I have am getting similar behavior...

Comment: yes, I have found solution but already lost it as client requested redo that part and I do not have ready solution now, try to with conditions and events but that definitely possible